# product code repeat in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this tables

**Product**

IDProd   ||  Name

**Time_Price**

IDPrice || IDProd || Price || Time

**the query is:**

> ```
> SELECT P.IDProd,P.Name,TP.Price,MAX(TP.Time)
>
> FROM Product P INNER JOIN Time_Price TP ON P.IDProd=TP.IDProd 
>
> GROUP BY P.IDProd,P.Name,TP.Price
> ```

**I need that the product code does not repeat**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the latest `Price` for every product.

```
SELECT  IDProd, Name,
        IDPrice, Price, Time
FROM
    (
        SELECT  a.IDProd, a.Name,
                b.IDPrice, b.Price, b.Time,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.IDProd ORDER BY b.Time DESC) rn
        FROM    Product a
                INNER JOIN Time_price b
                    ON a.IDProd = b.IDProd
    ) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

without using window function,

```
SELECT  a.IDProd, a.Name,
        b.IDPrice, b.Price, b.Time
FROM    Product a
        INNER JOIN Time_price b
            ON a.IDProd = b.IDProd
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  IDProd, MAX(Time) Time
            FROM    Time_price
            GROUP   BY IDProd
        ) c ON b.IDProd = c.IDProd AND
                b.Time = c.Time
```

Comment: can I change Row_Number for TOP ?

Comment: it will give you different result. unless your doing it with `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: This query is complex for what I'm doing. Thanks anyway, I will implement.

Comment: @Wfgo i have updated the answer by adding query that doesn't use window function. plain join and aggregate function only.